# Ambari server Installation in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I want to install Ambari server, following [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Install+Ambari+1.7.0+from+Public+Repositories) guide.

When I perform the step 1

> Download the Ambari repository on the Ambari Server host
>
> For Ubuntu:
>     cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
>     sudo wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu12/1.x/updates/1.7.0/ambari.list
>
> wget -nv http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu12/1.x/updates/1.7.0/ambari.list -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ambari.list 
>   apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD 
>   apt-get update

and step 2

> Install Ambari Server from the public Ambari repository:
>   For Ubuntu:
>     sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install ambari-server

I get the following error message

```
E: Unable to locate package ambari
```

Comment: Did you type `ambary-server`? It seems from the error that you did `sudo apt-get install ambari`.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... it was working fine a couple weeks ago - haven't changed the script.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mistyped somewhere. I have tried to follow guide you mentioned in description, and everything installs fine. Here is command sequence I tried:

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/ubuntu12/1.x/updates/1.7.0/ambari.list
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD
apt-get update
apt-get install ambari-server
```

Hope that helps

Comment: their is an issue with ubuntu key B9733A7A07513CAD

Comment: Can you please clarify what issue do you have and post output of commands you are trying to launch?